# Trying to access key from Object in Observable via async gives an error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have, what I would have thought, a very basic and simple **Object** that I **Get** via **Rx** and want to display a portion of on screen.

I trimmed all HTML and simply put down `{{ structure$ | async | json }}`, `structure$` being the name of the `Observable` in my component, defined like so:

```
structure$: Observable<Array<Object>>;
```

This displays the following:

```
{ 
  "navbar": [ 
   { "id": 5, "label": … , "order": 1 },
   { "id": 4, "label": … , "order": 2 }, 
   { "id": 6, "label": … , "order": 3 } ], 
  "sidebar": [
   { "id": 2, "label": … , "order": 1 },
   { "id": 1, "label": … , "order": 3 } ]
 }
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is display the `navbar`.
However, this `{{ structure$.navbar | async | json }}` renders nothing, nor does `{{ structure$.navbar | async }}` or `{{ structure$.['navbar'] | async | json }}` or even `{{ structure$.['navbar'] | async | json }}`.

Eventually what I am trying to achieve is a simple `*ngFor` on the navbar like so (doesn't work either of course):

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of structure$.navbar | async">
    {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Hello, I would try something like   `<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item.navbar as navItem of structure$| async">
    {{navItem}}
  </li>
</ul>`
Angular suggest somthing similar in its API https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just not using parentheses in the right way. You first want to get the async value and then access its property:

```
*ngFor="let item of (structure$ | async).navbar"
```

Then if you want to print the `navbar` you can use:

```
{{ (structure$ | async).navbar | json }}
```

Comment: Thanks @martin. Is this anywhere in the documentation? I have never come across it.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't remember seeing this anywhere either.